# DB Port - microservices development with the same DB on the same box

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I select PostgreSQL for the UAA and run it on Docker. Now, I create a microservice with the DB. After running it on Docker on the same box for development, I get an error due to the unavailable DB port. Is another way to solve the problem other than overriding the default DB port number in the microservice?

Comment: You could use same db container but different databases or schemas.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks very much for the information. That will be the DB configuration change in the Docker file, I guess.

Comment: I find an article on the subject: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/docker-dev-db . Some additional work is needed for JHipster microservices development.

Comment: The approach is to resolve a local development problem. The docker arrangement shouldn't be used in production. That seems to contradict the purpose of using Docker - the same system setting everywhere development or production.